# nuxtjs modify head tags programmatically

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

In my page i have the following head body attributes

```
export default{
  head: {
     bodyAttrs: {
      class: 'parallax-visible'
      }
   },
   methods:{
    modifyHeadTags(){
      //here change the body class
      //eg set like this.head.bodyAttrs.class="newclass"
      console.log("head is", this.head); //this is undefined 
     }
  }
```

Now the above function logs the head is undefined, How do i modify these header tags programmatically

so in the function i expect to do something like

```
this.head.bodyAttrs.class = "new class" //this one
```

Answer (score 1):

`head` is available inside `this.$options` along with `components`, `methods` and other attributes in `vueJs`

You can access head using `this.$options.head` inside method function.

So you need to do something like this inside the function,

```
this.$options.head.bodyAttrs.class="newclass"  //make sure bodyAttrs is defined in head object
```